Using YT-DLP in discord.py but the songs stop
I'm having a problem with this, I'm new and I want to make a discord bot using Python. The problem is when the bot enters a vc and starts the song it stops a few seconds after starting. I tried with youtube-dl but I read that they discontinued it and it didn't work when I tried it either
So that's the problem, any help please? this is the code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import yt_dlp
import config
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='m!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

#Bot startup

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} ready')

ffmpeg_options = {'options': '-vn'}

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'quiet': False,
    'noplaylist': False,
    'ignoreerrors': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
        
    }],
    
}

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    def add(self, item):
        self.queue.append(item)

    def remove(self):
        if self.queue:
            return self.queue.pop(0)
        return None

queue = Queue()


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("!Pong")

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
        await ctx.send("¡Necesitas estar en un canal de voz!")
        return
    
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is not None:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
    else:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    await ctx.send(f"Me he unido a {voice_channel}")


@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client is not None:
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("Bye Bye")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No estoy en un canal de voz")


#Using play

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
        await ctx.send("¡Necesitas estar en un canal de voz para usar este comando!")
        return
    
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    
    try:
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        if not vc:
            await voice_channel.connect()
            vc = ctx.voice_client

        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            
            info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{query}", download=False)
            url = info['entries'][0]['url']

            queue.add(url)
            if not vc.is_playing():
                play_next(ctx)
                await ctx.send(f"Reproduciendo: {info['entries'][0]['title']}")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"{info['entries'][0]['title']} añadida a la cola de reproducción")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al reproducir audio: {e}")
        await ctx.send("Ocurrió un error al reproducir el audio.")


@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client is None or not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await ctx.send("No hay nada reproduciéndose que se pueda saltar.")
        return

    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    await ctx.send("Canción skipped")
    play_next(ctx)

def play_next(ctx):
    url = queue.remove()
    if url:
        ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url), after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))


@bot.command()
async def disconnect(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await ctx.send("No estoy en un canal de voz.")
        return
    

    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("Me he desconectado del canal de voz.")


#Disconnect when nobody is in the vc

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if bot.user in member.guild.voice_channels and len(member.guild.voice_channels) == 1:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        if len(member.guild.voice_channels) == 1 and bot.user in member.guild.voice_channels:
            await member.guild.voice_client.disconnect()


bot.run(config.TOKEN)


Listen complete songs

`This is an English language only site. Please translate your title and the rest of your post, and remove the duplicate text. Using Google Translate is not acceptable. You have to be able to respond to questions in English, as well as read English text.

Sorry for the problems
